# Loading multiple rows of column to store as qvd

Tags: excel, loading, inline, multiple-columns, qlikview

I'm trying to load this table and store it as qvd. But the problem is I don't want to default header to appear in cell which only show header name in second row not first row. I also like to store A,B,C,D as Alphabet Group and avg score as another value. I have tried using crosstable and load inline but failed.

Your help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a picture showing what you expect the result table to look like?

Comment: duplicate post! this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391410/how-to-combine-column-name-as-a-list-in-qlikview/34409286?noredirect=1#comment56561537_34409286

Answer (score 1):

Crosstable is the way to go. You should calculate the average in the frontend.

If you can't get the crosstable working. Build the table manually.

It should have 3 columns (Subject, Alphabet group, score) and look like:

[image: Table]